# How should an empty timestamp variable be declared, in order to be a global var so we can give it a value later?

Tags: javascript, angular, timestamp

I want to set a timestamp as a global variable and set it with empty value. I want to use it inside the functions and assign a value to it. How this timestamp var should be declared?

For example, I have 2 buttons which each button triggers a method

```
<button (click)="startTime()">Starting timestamp</button>

<button (click)="endTime()">Ending timestamp</button>
```

I want to have two timestamp variables declared as global variables in component.ts , in order to get these dates when button are clicked and then update other methods.

Comment: please share a code sample and let us know where you got stuck. This way you can get help with your question. The question is too vague at the moment...

Comment: "call this var" - how do you "call a timestamp"? Also, what does this have to do with `angular`, `firebase`, and `google-cloud-firestore`?

Comment: Also by the time I need to get the date in a timestamp that requires a firebase format it has to do with firebase @ASDFGerte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the variable inside the class:

```
export class MyComponent {

  myTimestamp;
  myOtherTimestamp;

  startTime() {
    this.myTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
  }

  endTime() {
    this.myOtherTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
  }
}
```

For sharing with other components / services, you can add it to a singleton service and access it wherever you want:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MySharedService {
  myTimestamp;
}
```

and access it by injecting the service:

```
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private mySharedService: MySharedService ){}

  myCustomFunction() {
   this.mySharedService.myTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I use a service and I wanted to pass the timestamp as a parameter from a function call so it helped me a lot. Is it possible to set this timestamp date value to null in order to give it a value from another event. That will help me to check it in an if statement.Could this work? -> var myTimestamp = new Date(0); @yazantahhan

Comment: Sure. While the service is a singleton, then any value can be set and read from any place. But I'm not sure why do you want to set it to null, because the initial value when you declare `myTimestamp` is undefined. So you can just leave it as it if you don't want the `null` value explicitly.

Comment: Please note that you can use ES6 `let` and `const` instead of `var`

Comment: Okay I got it, it works fine , and I can make use of it when is set to undefined! Thanks a lot for you time!

Comment: Sure. Glad to help!